# Функция посимвольного сравнения строк без учета регистра

Tags: java, строки, char, сравнение

> Напишите функцию, которая принимает две строки a и b и сравнивает
> строки без учета регистра. Возвращает -1, если a < b. 0, если a == b.
> 1, если a > b.
>
> Строка может содержать символы с кодами с 32 по 126. Максимальная
> длина строки 10^6 символов.

Решаю эту задачу, но вывод получаю неверный.

Пожалуйста подскажите что именно не верно в моем коде

Вот код:

```java
public static int compareIgnoreCase(String a, String b){
        char [] arrayA = a.toCharArray();     // создание массива сивмолов первой строки и передача в него символов строки
        char [] arrayB = b.toCharArray();     // создание массива для передачи символов  второй строки
        int n = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);    // создание переменной для определения длинны массива

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){                // запуск цикла
            int numberAMin = arrayA[i] + 32;        // создание переменной для символа первого слова с противоположным регистром
            int numberBMin = arrayB[i] + 32;        // создание переменной для символа второго слова с противоположным регистром
            int numberAMax = arrayA[i] - 32;         //- //
            int numberBMax = arrayB[i] - 32;         // - //

            if (arrayA[i] < arrayB[i]               // создание условия, если символ первого слова меньше символа второго и не равен противоположному ргистру
                    && arrayA[i] != numberBMax
                    && arrayA[i] != numberBMin
                    && arrayB[i] != numberAMax
                    && arrayB[i] != numberAMin){
                return -1;
            }
            if (arrayA[i] > arrayB[i]
                    && arrayA[i] != numberBMax
                    && arrayA[i] != numberBMin
                    && arrayB[i] != numberAMax
                    && arrayB[i] != numberAMin){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if (arrayA.length < arrayB.length){
            return -1;
        }
        if (arrayA.length> arrayB.length){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

ВОТ РАБОЧИЙ ВАРИАНТ:

```
public static int compareIgnoreCase(String a, String b){
        char [] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
        char [] arrayB = b.toCharArray();
        int n = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            // Берем очередные символы из массивов
            char chA = arrayA[i];
            char chB = arrayB[i];
            // Если очередной символ находится в диапазоне верхнего регистра
            // И НЕ цифра, то смещаем его в диапазон нижнего регистра
            if (chA >= 'A' && chA <= 'Z' && !(chA >= '0' && chA <= '9')){
                chA += 32;
            }
            // Аналогично
            if (chB >= 'A' && chB <= 'Z' && !(chB >= '0' && chB <= '9')){
                chB += 32;
            }
            int sumA = 0;  sumA = sumA + chA;
            int sumB = 0;  sumB = sumB + chB;

            if (sumA < sumB){
                return -1;
            }
            if (sumA > sumB){
                return 1;
            }      
        }
        if (arrayA.length > arrayB.length)
            return 1;
        else if (arrayA.length < arrayB.length)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Если что ))) всем спасибо!!

Comment: Не понятно чем эта задача принципиально отличается от предыдущей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача сводится к тому, чтобы привести строки к одному регистру (если это цифра, то её не надо приводить, разумеется - добавьте такое условие), а вот потом уже сравнивать. И тогда это и будет "сравнение без учета регистра".
У вас есть два варианта, как это сделать.
Например, как посоветовал Alexander Chernin: получать массив `char[]` преобразованием из `String`, и перебирать каждый символ. Т.е. при переборе элементов массива Вы проверяете: если это буква, то какая? Например `(можно и наоборот, "безучетностьрегистра" останется та же (: )`, видите заглавную - приводите к строчной, видите строчную - оставляете, как есть.
И потом уже сравниваете значения `a[i]` и `b[i]`.

Или же можно сделать лаконичнее: поищите методы класса String `toLowerCase()` и `toUpperCase()`. На выходе имеете String, у которого все символы - одного регистра. А дальше просто сравниваете, одним циклом.)

И еще, попробуйте суммировать символы своих строк. Т.е. привели к одному регистру буквы, а дальше суммируете все элементы через цикл. Почему так? Потому что по таблице ASCII слово HELLO будет "меньше" слова RIVER, например. Хотя количество букв одно. Или, например, слова RIVER и STILL: видимо, мы должны вернуть -1, т.к. R "меньше" S. Но на деле суммы их кодов равны..

P.S. IDEA не под рукой, поэтому без кода, лень.)

Comment: https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ :) Но второй вариант ей не нужен, я уже предложил, но его отвергли

Comment: @AlexanderChernin о как, спасибо)) (хотя все равно после idea не хочется ничего руками писать :D)

жаль, было бы симпотишно.

Comment: Александр !! Огромное спасибо !!! Вы мне очень помогли, но выкидывает ошибку на платформе, поэтому пытаюсь разобраться, что не так, может я что-то не так написала - (

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель а код обновленный (тот, что сейчас пытаетесь отправить), прикрепите?)

Comment: Отправляю весь тот, код, который здесь написан, кроме класса main)

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель на здоровье! )

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель О! попробуйте суммировать символы своих строк. 
Т.е. привели к одному регистру буквы, а дальше "пока элемент массива не null" суммируете элементы. 
Почему так? Потому что по таблице ASCII слово HELLO будет "меньше" слова RIVER, например. Хотя кол-ва букв одно.
Или, например, слова RIVER и STILL: видимо, мы должны вернуть -1, т.к. R "меньше" S. Но на деле суммы их кодов равны..

Comment: benderje
 Спасибо !!!

Answer (score 2):

Не буду расписывать, что у вас не так, а просто напишу как оно должно быть по логике (для латинского диапазона символов):

```
public static int compareIgnoreCase(String a, String b){
        char [] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
        char [] arrayB = b.toCharArray();
        
        int n = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Берем очередные символы из массивов
            char chA = arrayA[i];
            char chB = arrayB[i];
            
            // Если очередной символ находится в диапазоне верхнего регистра 
            // И НЕ цифра, то смещаем его в диапазон нижнего регистра
            if (chA >= 'A' && chA <= 'Z')
                chA += 32;
            // Аналогично
            if (chB >= 'A' && chB <= 'Z')
                chB += 32;              
  
            // Если символы не равны, то
            if (chA != chB) {
                // Какая строка длиннее  
                if (arrayA.length > arrayB.length) 
                    return 1;
                else if (arrayA.length < arrayB.length) 
                    return -1;
                // Строки оказались одинаковой длины, тогда
                // сравним какой символ "меньше"
                return chA < chB ? -1: 1;
            }
        }
        
        // Ну, тут все понятно
        if (arrayA.length > arrayB.length) 
            return 1;
        else if (arrayA.length < arrayB.length) 
            return -1;
        
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(compareIgnoreCase("Str1", "str1")); // 0
    }
```

Вариант сравнения сумм кодов символов строк:

```
char [] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
char [] arrayB = b.toCharArray();
    

int sumA = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    char chA = arrayA[i];
    if (chA >= 'A' && chA <= 'Z')
        chA += 32;    
    sumA += (int)chA;
}
       
int sumB = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    char chB = arrayB[i];
    if (chB >= 'A' && chB <= 'Z')
        chB += 32;    
    sumB += (int)chB;
}
return sumA == sumB ? 0 : (sumA < sumB? -1: 1);
```

Comment: Мне нужно написать функцию, не через сравнение строк, а перевести строки в тип char  и сравнивать символы между собой,

Comment: Поэтому здесь нужно работать со строками как с массивами символов

Comment: Если можете помочь  - что не так в моем коде?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель а что вы пытаетесь сделать в вашем коде? Вы можете прокомментировать строки кода. И, кстати, посмотрел ваши предыдущий такой же вопрос и там уже есть ответ. В чем проблема?

Comment: В настоящей задаче условие сравнение строк без учета регистра

Comment: В предыдущей задаче мы просто сравнивали строки и возвращали ответ

Comment: Комменатрии прописала

Comment: Я в настоящей задаче запуталась в том. как именно нужно сравнить без учета регистра..

Comment: все понятно, кроме:    // Одинаковые, тогда
                return chA < chB ? -1: 1;
            }

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель да, признаю неточность в выражении мысли - исправил

Comment: Вроде бы в Вашем коде мне все понятно, но платформа, на которой сдаю задачу - пишет ошибку - не верный вариант ответа, вместо -1 возвращает 1

Comment: Вот сижу и еще разбираюсь))

Comment: Может быть после того как мы сравнили вот здесь: // Строки оказались одинаковой длины, тогда
                // сравним какой символ "меньше"
                return chA < chB ? -1: 1;
            }

Comment: нужно прописать: } else { return 0 }  я конечно попробовала но не верно, сижу дальше думаю... что не так

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель для какого варианта вместо -1 возвращает 1?

Comment: Входные данные: a = "ITman";
b = "Java";

Comment: Ожидаемый результат: result = -1;  Результат вашего решения: result = 1;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138385/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and--).

Comment: Alexander Chernin ! думаю, что Ваш вариант тоже рабочий)) но не проверяла....

Comment: Да на платформе проверила вариант сравнения сумм символов без сравнения символов по-отдельности - тоже работает !!!! СПАСИБО ВАМ ВСЕМ ОГРОМНОЕ ОЧЕНЬ МНЕ ПОМОГЛИ !!! Желаю всем Удачи!!!